# Setting master pages programmatically for entire application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I know the following will set the master page programmatically in an ASP.NET VB.NET application:

```
Me.MasterPageFile = "~/masterPage.master"
```

Is it possible to programmatically set a master page file that would apply to all pages across an application, instead of having to set it for each individual page?  I want to be able to retrieve this value from a database in order to set the master page file to use.

If not, is it possible to set more than one master page file in the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what You can do with ASP.NET C#. I didnt test it with VB.

Declare Your own page class and set master page there for all Your pages:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    void Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "MasterPage.master";
    }
}
```

Inherit from Your own page class for each page that You create:

```
public partial class _Default : MyPage
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in your web.config file:

```
<pages masterPageFile="~/Template.master" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change settings of pages in the web.config. This code will change the master page for all pages.

```
    var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    SystemWebSectionGroup section=new SystemWebSectionGroup();
    section.Pages.MasterPageFile = "~/YourMasterPage.master";//Here too.
    configuration.Save();
```

Just keep in mind that making changes to the web.config restarts the webserver and invalidates the cache. So do not do it often.

I recommend you to individually do it for the pages in the PreInit event. I posted this code to show you that its possible to change for all pages at once, but it has its consequences.